# Geb form-control shortcuts - howto

Tags: geb

Following the Book of Geb guidelines here: [book of geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#form-control-shortcuts) it seems it should be possible to have easy access to form-elements, such as text input fields etc - just using the name.

The examples however fail to mention a complete example, and I cannot seem to get it to work. How is this construct suppose to be like?

Imagine a module with a specific base - the form it self - and list of form-elements to interact with in the content section (specified via name):

```
class MyFormModule extends Module {
    static base = { $('form#myForm') }
    static content = {
        mytextfield { textfield.mytextfield }
    }
}
```

This is inspired by the "geb" example in the book. It clearly doesn't work since "textfield" is not a valid property.

Is there any shortcuts for dooing like above? - I need to be able to have dots in the name. (I know I can write a selector - but this is a question about "form-control shortcuts")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want your content definition to return the `textarea` element and not it's value then you need to use a method and not a property and given that your element has a dot in its name you have to quote the method name because a method name call contain a dot:

```
class MyFormModule extends Module {
    static base = { $('form#myForm') }
    static content = {
        mytextfield { "textfield.mytextfield"() }
    }
}
```

Given that Geb also has shortcuts for setting and accessing values of elements defined as page and module contents (describe at the end of the section you linked to) and the following page class:

```
class MyPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        myform { module(MyFormModule) }
    }
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
go MyPage
form.mytextfield = "foo"
assert form.mytextfield == "foo"
```

Secondly you can access and set value of the element named `textfield.mytextfield` directly on the module (without using the module's content definition) using form control shortcuts:

```
go MyPage
form."textarea.mytextfield" = "foo"
assert form."textarea.mytextfield" == "foo"
```

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I expected I would be able to do - I'll try it out and get back with some votes, if it works :) Thanks for ur reply!